# my function priceFilter() is not working properly

Tags: javascript

Create a function called priceFilter that returns all the items whose price is under a certain amount.

The function should take in two arguments, an array of items and an amount (a number)
return an array of items that have a price below the amount.
For example, here's what the function should return when we pass in the sample items and the amount 50:

I still have two problems testCart2 returns undefined for some reason even though it prints all the correct items. I set the for loop to run until end of array so not sure why its undefined instead of just ending at the last item like the rest do. The second issue is that an empty array should return [].

I will enter all the code I have so far for the project so anyone can test it. Thank you for your help.

```js
const sampleCart = [{
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

const testCart1 = [{
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 18.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Orangebook Pro",
    type: "computer",
    price: 899.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  },
  {
    itemName: "Fabulous Algorithms",
    type: "book",
    price: 29.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Another Item",
    type: "clothes",
    price: 25.00
  }
]

const testCart2 = [{
    itemName: "Pencil Case",
    type: "supplies",
    price: 2.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Spiral Notebook",
    type: "supplies",
    price: 4.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Pack of 10 Pencils",
    type: "supplies",
    price: 8.20
  },
  {
    itemName: "Ballpoint Pen",
    type: "supplies",
    price: 2.20
  },
  {
    itemName: "Eraser",
    type: "supplies",
    price: .99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Stapler",
    type: "supplies",
    price: 3.99
  }
]

const testCart3 = []

function cartPrice(items) { //328.98
  let totalPrice = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    totalPrice += items[i].price;
  }
  return totalPrice;
}


function priceLookup(items, itemNames) {
  for ({
      itemName,
      price
    } of items) {
    if (itemName === itemNames) {
      return price;
    }
  }
}


function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  items.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
  let highestPrice = 0;
  for ({
      itemName,
      price
    } of items) {
    if (price > highestPrice) {
      highestPrice = price;
      highestPrice = itemName;
    }
    return highestPrice
  }
}

function priceFilter(items, number) {
  items.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
  for (let i = 0; items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].price < number) {
      console.log(items[i]);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

priceFilter(testCart2, 50);
```

Comment: Your function just prints the selected items, it doesn't return them.

Comment: There's no need to sort the array. Just use `items.filter()`.

Comment: `items.length` should be `i < items.length`

Comment: As Barmar say, you can use items.filter(). By the way, if you want to keep your functions in this way, you need to return the items. Nothing is returning in those functions

Comment: there is something wrong with testCart2 JSON

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice and the quick replies on this the filter fixed the issue. I'm just learning the language so didn't know this option was available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const testCart1 = [{
itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
type: "book",
price: 18.99
  },
  {
itemName: "Creation 3005",
type: "computer",
price: 399.99
  },
  {
itemName: "Orangebook Pro",
type: "computer",
price: 899.99
  },
  {
itemName: "Finding Your Center",
type: "book",
price: 15.00
  },
  {
itemName: "Fabulous Algorithms",
type: "book",
price: 29.99
  },
  {
itemName: "Another Item",
type: "clothes",
price: 25.00
  }
]

function priceFilter(items, number) {
  return items.filter(item => item.price <= number)
}

console.log(priceFilter(testCart1, 50))
```

Comment: Thanks so much this function you made worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you didn't mention the condition this is why it is not working as expected.

```
function priceFilter(items, number) {
  items.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
  for (let i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {  //add condiiton
    if (items[i].price < number) {
      console.log(items[i]);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

}
```